# Query to Read from three tables toin php

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are many simillar threads, but neither one did not find what I need.

I have three tables `my_resource` , `my_user` , `my_resource_featured`

I want to read only featured data. I build a query to read all data, 
This is my code:

```
 $FRArray = $db->fetchAll($db->limit("SELECT
        resource_id, title, tag_line,
        icon_date, last_update, price, currency, resource_state,
        user.user_id, user.username
        FROM my_resource AS resource
        LEFT JOIN my_user AS user ON (user.user_id = resource.user_id)
        WHERE resource.resource_id
        AND resource_state = 'visible'
        ORDER BY resource.rating_weighted DESC, resource.last_update DESC",
    $Limit));
```

`my_resource id` and `my_resource_featured id` is same.

e.x If id1 and id3 from `my_resource` are featured, then same id's are write to `my_resource_featured`

What I miss that I can do this?

Regards,

Comment: Can you show us your table schema?

Comment: you can select a column by specifying a table name ahead the column 
e.g 
select table_name.column_name from table_name

Comment: sure `my_resource` http://prntscr.com/e4h1gu
`my_user` http://prntscr.com/e4h227 and `my_resource_featured` http://prntscr.com/e4h2c4

Comment: post table structure with desired output

Comment: @denny i want to output resource  whose id coincide with the id of the table `my_resource_featured`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you, though you may want to rethink your column names

```
SELECT 
  resource.resource_id,
  feature_date
  title, 
  tag_line,
  icon_date,
  last_update,
  price,
  currency,
  resource_state,
  user.user_id, 
  user.username
FROM my_resource AS resource
INNER JOIN my_resource_featured
  ON (my_resource_featured.resource_id = resource.resource_id)
INNER JOIN my_user AS user 
  ON (user.user_id = resource.user_id)
WHERE 
  resource_state = 'visible'
ORDER BY
  resource.rating_weighted DESC,
  resource.last_update DESC";
```

if it were me:

my_resource's primary key would just be id not resource_id, and same with my_user (eg. `my_user.id = my_resource.user_id`, and `my_resource_featured.resource_id = my_resource.id`).

any time your are referencing your table name in your columns names, you are on the wrong track.  references to OTHER tables should have the table name in the column.